# Does the F-4E Phantom II have a weather radar?

Tags: fighter, radar, f-4, weather-radar

Here's the cockpit of the F-4E:

---

[image: F-4E Cockpit]

---

The Main Panel NO7 says "Radar Scope" and when you put your mouse cursor on that "magician globe", the X-Plane 8.15 tooltip says "Weather Radar". So, what is that overly "oversized weather radar scope"?

Comment: Related? [AN/APQ-120](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/APQ-120)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is based on a video game.

Comment: @RalphJ Whether the F-4 has a weather radar does not seem off-topic, regardless of what prompted the question. Voting to leave open.

Comment: @RalphJ I am not asking anything about the F4 In the X-Plane ! I am asking if F4E P2 have an "weather radar" in the real life !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The F-4 radar was a low PRF pulse radar, designed to search for, acquire, and track other airborne aircraft, and then provide guidance for Aim-7 Sparrow air-to-air missiles. It also had a ground mapping capability, and a capability to detect and display severe weather, but it was primarily designed for air-to-air combat.

Later models of the F-4 had an more modern radar, (installed in the German F-4F for example) which was a high PRF pulse Doppler system, and had improved capabilities, but I don't know whether they still had a weather mapping capability. I would be surprised if they did not.